# Mapping duplicate

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, mapping

I have a mapping in my smart contract, which works as a user's historic. Each time the user adds or transfer a kit, the information about this said kit has added to the mapping. These kits have an id which is unique and a description.

In order to avoid duplicate I created a function, `checkDuplicate`, that check if the kit wasn't previously added for the current user. This function works by iterating the mapping for the current user and checking if the kit's id isn't already in the array list.

Here is the said code:

```
contract Trial{
    
    struct Kit{
        uint256 id;
        string description;
    }
    
    mapping (address => Kit[]) public historic;
    uint256 public kitCount = 0;
    
    function checkDuplicate(Kit memory _kit) internal{
        uint256 _id = _kit.id;
        bool _res = true;
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < historic[msg.sender].length; i++){
            if(_id == historic[msg.sender][i].id){
                _res = false;
            }
        }
        if(_res = true){
            historic[msg.sender].push(_kit);
        }
    }
    
    function addKit(string memory _description) public{
        Kit memory newKit = Kit(kitCount, _description);
        checkDuplicate(newKit);
        kitCount++;
    }
    
    function transfertKit(uint256 _id, string memory _description) public {
        Kit memory newKit = Kit(_id, _description);
        checkDuplicate(newKit);
    }
}
```

The problem is quite easy, my function `checkDuplicate` doesn't work as intended. With the same address, I first added a kit, `addict`, before transferring it, `transfertKit`. However, my map unregistered both of them, even thought it's the same kit (same id).

I would like to ask for some help about this problem please. I really can't find out where is the problem.

Comment: You have an error in the code posted `if(_res = true){` doesn't not compile with recent solc versions, ie 0.4.xx, 0.6.yy.

Comment: @Ismael I want to kill myself, I wasted over two hours for such a stupid error... Thanks a lot for your help ! Have a good day :D !

Comment: Does `if(_res = true)` actually compiles???

Comment: Also, function `checkDuplicate` will revert on out of gas as soon as `historic[msg.sender]` becomes too long. This is not how you wanna implement this requirement.

Comment: @goodvibration Ok thanks for the advice :D !